# $\int_{0}^{\frac{5}{4}} \frac{x+\sqrt{x+1}}{2x-3\sqrt{x+1}} \, dx$

Tags: real-analysis

I have to solve this integral:

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{5}{4}} \frac{x+\sqrt{x+1}}{2x-3\sqrt{x+1}} \, dx$$
 I tried with the substitution $u=\sqrt{x+1}=g^{-1}(x)\Rightarrow x=u^2-1=g(u) \Rightarrow  dx= g'(u)du=2udu$

then the integral becomes:
$$\int \frac{2u^3+2u^2-2u}{2u^2-3u-2} \, du$$

Dividing the numerator :
$$\int (u+\frac{5}{2} )\, du+\int \frac{\frac{15}{2}u+5}{2u^2-3u-2} \, du=$$
$$\int (u+\frac{5}{2} )\, du+\frac{5}{4}\int \frac{3u+2}{(u-2)(u+\frac{1}{2})} \, du$$
$$=\int (u+\frac{5}{2} )\, du+\frac{5}{4}\int \frac {16}{5}\frac{1}{(u-2)} \, du+\frac{5}{4}\int (-\frac {1}{5})\frac{1}{(u+\frac{1}{2})} \, du=$$
$$\frac{u^2}{2}+\frac{5}{2}u+4\log|u-2|-\frac{1}{4}\log|u+\frac{1}{2}|=$$
$$\frac{x+1}{2}+\frac{5}{2} \sqrt{x+1}+4\log|\sqrt{x+1}-2|-\frac{1}{4}\log|\sqrt{x+1}-\frac{1}{2}|+C$$

The right result for the indefinite integral is:
$$\frac{x+1}{2}+\frac{5}{2} \sqrt{x+1}+4\log(2-\sqrt{x+1})-\frac{1}{4}\log(2\sqrt{x+1}+1)+C$$

and I don't understand why it is writtem $(2-\sqrt{x+1})$ instead of $|\sqrt{x+1}-2|$ and the difference in the last integral $-\frac{1}{4}\log(2\sqrt{x+1}+1)$ and $-\frac{1}{4}\log|\sqrt{x+1}-\frac{1}{2}|$

Can someone explain me why?

Comment: What is the value of $\sqrt{x+1}$ when $x$ is between $0$ and $5/4$? Is it less than or greater than $2$?

Comment: @ZubinMnhaveukerjee I think I have understood: when  $0<x< \frac{5}{4} $,    $\sqrt{x+1}<2$ and then $|\sqrt{x+1}-2|=2-\sqrt{x+1}$

Comment: @Fabio yes. indeed, I've edited the text